# Http request issue of aws ip4 address

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-deployment, mern

I have deployed the web on aws ec2 instance using ubuntu. Now I have made a request to http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup
but it is showing http://{ip4 address}/api/users/signup. Please guide me about the issue.
backend is running on the port 5000.
I am using the nginx web server.
[Browser response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkBHe.png)

Comment: Please supply more details on the setup. When deploying web server on a remote machine in the cloud. You will have to configure this machine accesses from the internet and connect to it using this IP.

Comment: server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  # react app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /home/ubuntu/med/frontend/deploy;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
  }
}   // typed in the /etc/nginx/sites-available in the default file

Comment: I have only pasted the build files in the frontend deploy folder

Comment: I have not clonned it from the git

Comment: I have made a folder name med , which has two folders 1.backend 2.frontend . the backend folder has the totally code for backend files models, controllers, routes, app.js, package.json. In the frontend I have the only deploy folder which has the build files.

Comment: Now the issue is I want to hit http://localhost:5000/api/users, but it is hitting http://{ip4address}/api/users